# WinForms - Custom Collections & Collection Editor

Tags: winforms, collections, user-controls, custom-controls

I want to create a user control that the user can add buttons to it at design time.

So I've created a class called ButtonsContainer that inherits from UserControl, I've also created a class ButtonsCollection that inherits from CollectionBase, in the ButtonsContainer class (the user control) i put a property of type ButtonsCollection so that the user can add buttons to the collection at design time.

Now i want that when the user will add a button through the collection editor (at design time), that button will be visible on the user control, so i put an event ButtonAdded in the ButtonsCollection class and that event is triggered when the ButtonsCollection's Add function is called. But it does not work, when i place the user control on the form and i add buttons through the collection editor that buttons are not visible on the user control, just when i run the program (i.e. in run time) i see the buttons that i've added at design time visible on the user control, the code:

Class ButtonsCollection:

```
[Serializable]
public class ButtonsCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public ButtonsCollection() {}

    public event EventHandler ButtonAdded;

    public void Add(Button button)
    {
        List.Add(button);   
        ButtonAdded?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());                       
    }
}
```

Class ButtonsContainer:

```
Designer(typeof(ParentControlDesigner))
public partial class ButtonsContainer : UserControl
{
    public ButtonsContainer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Buttons = new ButtonsCollection();
        Buttons.ButtonAdded += new EventHandler(ButtonAdded);
    }

    private void ButtonAdded(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn = Buttons[Buttons.Count - 1];
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Location = new Point(1, Buttons.Count * btn.Size.Height);
        btn.Visible = true;
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ButtonsCollection Buttons
    {
        get; private set;
    } 
}
```

Note: when i click the Buttons property in the property grid a CollectionEditor form shows up.

As we can see, the event ButtonAdded is triggered fine, but when i add buttons manually (at design time) through the Buttons property (the collection editor), that buttons are not visible on the user control.

Basically, i want to add buttons through the collection editor in the Buttons property and see them on the user control immediately after i press the "Add" button of the collection editor form.